# Dynamicly pass table name to LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a machines list stored in my DB, but they are separated from them type in diferent tables.

Example:

**Table Name** : **Rows**

- MachineType1: Machine 1, Machine2, Machine3
- MachineType2: Machine 1, Machine2, Machine3, Machine 4
- MachineType3: Machine 1, Machine2

And I have another table that stores the type of machine, like this:

- Type1, MachineType1
- Type2, MachineType2
- Type3, MachineType3

I need to go through every type of machine (ie: Type2), get the table name (ie: MachineType2), go through that table and get the Id of every machine (ie: 1, 2, 3 and 4).

I did a lot of research but I couldn´t find anything that helps me.

Here is what i´m trying to do:

```
foreach (var process in processes) {
   var dynamictable =
      (from t in _context.PlasticProcess // This table has all types of machines and table names
       where (t.Id == process)
       select t.MachineName
      ).First();

   IEnumerable<int> machine =
      from x in _context.dynamictable // (Here is the problem)
      select x.Id;
}
```

Comment: You'll find that functionality in the `System.Linq.Dynamic` namespace.  See [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) and [here](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic).

Comment: I did it and I´m really glad you shared this. The problem is that I can´t find anything to make the table name a parameter. Only the conditions to the query.

Comment: Your best bet might be to craft a SQL statement using string manipulation, and hand that string directly to your EF context.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: I couldn´t do it, but thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: your second query, where you have said "here is the problem", you are referring to `_context.dynamictable`, but `dynamictable` is a variable. it should just be `from x in dynamictable`. not sure if that is the only issue.

Comment: The problem is that **dynamictable** is a string. Linq won´t recognize it as table to query.

Comment: right sorry, I see now. how many of these tables are there? can you just define your own mapping by name? or would it be too long or change too often and be unmaintainable? Also, is this Entity Framework?

Comment: Unfortunately, the tables are generated by a UI. And yes, i´m using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Would calling the non-generic [`DbContext.Set()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext_Set_System_Type_) help you? I am assuming `t.MachineName` is a string, update appropriately otherwise.

```
foreach (var process in processes) {
   var dynamictable =
      (from t in _context.PlasticProcess // This table has all types of machines and table names
       where (t.Id == process)
       select t.MachineName
      ).First();

    var set = _context.Set(Type.GetType(dynamicTable));
    // use set.SqlQuery here.
}
```

You can read about DbSet.SqlQuery() method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbSet_SqlQuery_System_String_System_Object___).

**P.S.:** I just realized that no where do you mention whether this is EF or not. This answer assumes it is EF.

Comment: Tanveer, thank you very much for your time! I had this problem: I got an error CS1501. It says that no overload for "Set" takes one parameter -> **Set<TEntity>()**. Do you know how to solve this? And yes, i´m using EF.

Comment: But I´ll try to solve this with **DbSet.SqlQuery()** also.

Comment: Weird error, you have there. Might be API conflict between EF and EF core. The one I linked to is for EF6.x.

Comment: I´ll try to solve this with Raw Sql, thank you very much!